# Creating a new thread for UI in Android

Tags: ui-thread

I created an Activity, after that I created a thread which reads from the phone book, do some string manipulation and based on the rules, creates various buttons on the main UI.

I am having the code below but some how the application terminates.

Can anyone please help me.

```
public class Phone extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ProgressDialog pbarDialog;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Button b;

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);
        setContentView(sv);
        pbarDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pbarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pbarDialog.setMessage("Reading from Phone Book");
        pbarDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pbarDialog.show();
        pbarDialog.incrementProgressBy(0);     



        new TheTask().execute();                       

    }


    private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pbarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pbarDialog.setMessage("Reading from Phone Book");
            pbarDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pbarDialog.show();
            pbarDialog.incrementProgressBy(0);         
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ReadPhoneBook();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pbarDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }    



    private void ReadPhoneBook() {
        int i=0;             
        int count=0;
        //this is a temp function, it just creates buttons, does not read the phone book.
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {           
            b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("Testing");            
            b.setId(1);
            final Activity self = this;
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    initiateACall(v,self);
                }
            });
            ll.addView(b);  
            if (i%3 == 0){
                pbarDialog.incrementProgressBy(30*i/3);
            }
        }

    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> 06-24 21:52:36.274: WARN/dalvikvm(297): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:594)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1200)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1863)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at ReadPhoneBook(IndiaCalling.java:148)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at access$0(IndiaCalling.java:133)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at $TheTask.doInBackground(IndiaCalling.java:79)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at $TheTask.doInBackground(IndiaCalling.java:1)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   06-24 21:52:36.436: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(297):     ... 4 more
>   06-24 21:52:36.564: WARN/ActivityManager(67):   Force finishing activity net.WhileOne.IndiaCalling/.IndiaCalling
>   06-24 21:52:37.534: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44eab020
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297): Activity Phone has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eeacf8 that was originally added here
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity Phone has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eeacf8 that was originally added here
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:247)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at Phone.onCreate(Phone.java:47)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   06-24 21:52:39.004: ERROR/WindowManager(297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: How does it terminate? Generate an error?  What does the log look like?

Answer (score 0):

This stats your thread using Android's AsyncTask class:

```
new TheTask().execute();
```

However, I don't understand why you're staring new threads in addition:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){          
                //Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                ReadPhoneBook();
                pbarDialog.dismiss();
            }           
        }).start();
```

Why not use one or the other?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to comment it, let me update it... Even after commenting it, it is not working..

Comment: put ReadPhoneBook method in the TheTask class or add 'synchronized' to ReadPhoneBook method signature

Comment: Tried both a) putting ReadPhoneBook method in TheTAsk class and b)adding synchronized to ReadPhoneBook methond, It is still not working...

Comment: Fixed the issue. Was trying to update the view in the main activity from the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Was trying to update the view in the main activity from the thread.